# How to add a checkbox in pageblocktable row?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I need to show all the custom object records in pageblocktable. Before populating all the records i need to add a picklist value, Checkbox in the first row and then populate all the records. How can i do that.

```
Name    Satisfy Opportunity            Status             Last modified                           
                                   Status(Picklist) 
        Turn on all checkbox     Turn on all checkbox   
             Clear all                Clear all 
Test 1       Checkbox                 Checkbox             12/12/2014
Test 2       Checkbox                 Checkbox             12/12/2014
Test 3       Checkbox                 Checkbox             12/12/2014
```

VF code:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Opportunity" extensions="oppgapstatus">
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock> 
<apex:pageBlockSection id="Info">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!WrapperList}" var="wraprec">
<apex:column value="{!wraprec.accRec.Name__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!wraprec.accRec.Satisfied__c}"/>  
<apex:column value="{!wraprec.accRec.Current_Status__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!wraprec.accRec.LastModifiedDate}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!UpdateSelectedRecords}"/>
<apex:commandbutton value="Cancel"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
Public class oppgapstatus{
 Public Opportunity optyList{get;set;}
 Public Opportunity_Status__c opst{get;set;}
  public PageReference openPresentationOptions() {
      return null;
   }

 private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
 public oppgapstatus(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
 }
//Checkbox selectall        
Public List<wrapperclass> wrapList {get;set;}
Public boolean checked{get;set;}
Public string selectedField {get;set;}
Public string inputVal{get;set;}
  Public void selectallnone(){
    if(!checked)
      checked = true;
    else
      checked = false;

 }
  Public List<wrapperclass> getWrapperList(){
   wrapList = New List<wrapperclass>();
   for(Opportunity_Status__c acc:[select name,Satisfied__c,Current_Status__c,LastModifiedDate from Opportunity_Gaps__c where Opportunity_Detail__c =: optyList.Id]){
     if(!checked)
     wrapList.add(New wrapperclass(acc,false)); 
     else
     wrapList.add(New wrapperclass(acc,true));   
   } 
   return wrapList; 
  }
   Public class wrapperclass{
   Public Opportunity_Status__c accRec{get;set;}
   Public boolean checkFlag{get;set;}

   Public wrapperclass(Opportunity_Status__c acc,boolean flag){
    accRec = acc;
    checkFlag = flag;
    }
   }
```

Can anyone help me..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the

```
<apex:column value="{!wraprec.accRec.Name__c}"/>
```

to

```
<apex:column> <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wraprec.accRec.boolean_Field__c}"/></apex:column>
```

You can even write `onchange` action as well in the